# ActiveMQ Artemis: javax.jms.IllegalStateRuntimeException: Session is closed after interruption in PostgreSQL DB connection

Tags: postgresql, activemq-artemis

Recently we have upgraded ActiveMQ Artemis version from 1.5.3 to 2.21.0 and now using PostgreSQL to store the messages. Earlier we were storing the messages in file system.

ActiveMQ Artemis is used as a embedded server inside a Spring-based Java web application.

We are getting following error if connection to the PostgreSQL is temporarily interrupted:

```
javax.jms.IllegalStateRuntimeException: Session is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.JmsExceptionUtils.convertToRuntimeException(JmsExceptionUtils.java:59)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSContext.createMapMessage(ActiveMQJMSContext.java:257)
    at com..data.core.messaging.dataload.BaseDataLoaderMessageSender.getMapMessage(BaseDataLoaderMessageSender.java:220)
    at com.test.data.core.messaging.dataload.BaseDataLoaderMessageSender.send(BaseDataLoaderMessageSender.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Session is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession.checkClosed(ActiveMQSession.java:1255)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession.createMapMessage(ActiveMQSession.java:169)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSContext.createMapMessage(ActiveMQJMSContext.java:255)
    ... 132 more
```

The sequeunce of events are

1. Start the server
2. Shutdown DB
3. Perform some action on JMS queue like send a message/read messages from queue - It will fail. This is expected
4. Start DB
5. Perform some action on JMS queue like send a message/read messages from queue

In the step 5 as the connection is restored then I expect it to be successful.

ConnectionFactory is created as a Spring bean:

```xml
    <bean id="queueConnectionFactory"
          class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg value="false"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.TransportConfiguration">
                <constructor-arg
                        value="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="ConsumerWindowSize" value="0"/>
    </bean>
```

And the `JMSContext` and `MessageProducer` are being created as

```java
jmsContext = connectionFactory.createContext();
producer = jmsContext.createProducer();
```

Note: I tried to recreate ConnectionFactory programatically in case of exception but still the same issue.

Can anyone suggest what can be wrong here?

**Edit 1:**
Error log in case of DB connection is lost

```
[INFO ] 2022-06-24 10:28:53.353 [MessageBroker-1] WebSocketMessageBrokerStats - WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
[ERROR] 2022-06-24 10:29:11.737 [Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@4d16a1c0)] JDBCConnectionProvider - 
SQL EXCEPTIONS: 
SQLState: 08001 ErrorCode: 0 Message: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
[WARN ] 2022-06-24 10:29:11.737 [Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@4d16a1c0)] JDBCJournalImpl - Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:739) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:671) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:194) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.drivers.JDBCConnectionProvider.getConnection(JDBCConnectionProvider.java:61) ~[artemis-jdbc-store-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.journal.JDBCJournalImpl.sync(JDBCJournalImpl.java:213) ~[artemis-jdbc-store-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.journal.JDBCJournalImpl$JDBCJournalSync.run(JDBCJournalImpl.java:1049) ~[artemis-jdbc-store-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent.runForExecutor(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:313) ~[artemis-commons-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent.lambda$bookedRunForScheduler$2(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:320) ~[artemis-commons-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) ~[artemis-commons-2.21.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) ~[artemis-commons-2.21.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65) ~[artemis-commons-2.21.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.21.0.jar:?]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[?:?]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    ... 28 more
[WARN ] 2022-06-24 10:29:11.833 [Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@4d16a1c0)] server - AMQ222010: Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. file=NULL, message=Critical IO Error.  Failed to process JDBC Record statements
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:739) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:671) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:194) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.drivers.JDBCConnectionProvider.getConnection(JDBCConnectionProvider.java:61) ~[artemis-jdbc-store-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.journal.JDBCJournalImpl.sync(JDBCJournalImpl.java:213) ~[artemis-jdbc-store-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.journal.JDBCJournalImpl$JDBCJournalSync.run(JDBCJournalImpl.java:1049) ~[artemis-jdbc-store-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent.runForExecutor(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:313) ~[artemis-commons-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent.lambda$bookedRunForScheduler$2(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:320) ~[artemis-commons-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) ~[artemis-commons-2.21.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) ~[artemis-commons-2.21.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65) ~[artemis-commons-2.21.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.21.0.jar:?]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[?:?]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    ... 28 more
[INFO ] 2022-06-24 10:29:11.845 [Thread-12] load - preDeActivate called
[WARN ] 2022-06-24 10:29:11.923 [Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@4d16a1c0)] server - AMQ222057: It was not possible to add references due to an IO error code 6 message = JDBC Transaction failed.
[WARN ] 2022-06-24 10:29:11.923 [Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@4d16a1c0)] server - AMQ222063: Error processing IOCallback code = 6 message = JDBC Transaction failed.
[INFO ] 2022-06-24 10:30:04.019 [Thread-12] load - deActivate called
[WARN ] 2022-06-24 10:30:04.112 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] client - AMQ212037: Connection failure to invm:0 has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
[WARN ] 2022-06-24 10:30:04.112 [Thread-3 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] client - AMQ212037: Connection failure to invm:0 has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
[WARN ] 2022-06-24 10:30:04.112 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] client - AMQ212037: Connection failure to invm:0 has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
[WARN ] 2022-06-24 10:30:04.112 [Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] client - AMQ212037: Connection failure to invm:0 has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
[INFO ] 2022-06-24 10:30:04.147 [Thread-12] load - stop called
[ERROR] 2022-06-24 10:30:04.575 [DataLoad-EventLoadMessageProcessorThread] load - AMQ219017: Consumer is closed
javax.jms.IllegalStateRuntimeException: AMQ219017: Consumer is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.JmsExceptionUtils.convertToRuntimeException(JmsExceptionUtils.java:59) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConsumer.receive(ActiveMQJMSConsumer.java:68) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at com.test.data.core.messaging.dataload.BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.processMessagesInBatch(BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.java:108) [test-core-base-data-loader-22.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.test.data.core.messaging.dataload.BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.run(BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.java:80) [test-core-base-data-loader-22.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: AMQ219017: Consumer is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.checkClosed(ClientConsumerImpl.java:951) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(ClientConsumerImpl.java:198) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(ClientConsumerImpl.java:382) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.getMessage(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:209) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:129) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConsumer.receive(ActiveMQJMSConsumer.java:66) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQObjectClosedException: AMQ219017: Consumer is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.checkClosed(ClientConsumerImpl.java:951) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(ClientConsumerImpl.java:198) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(ClientConsumerImpl.java:382) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.getMessage(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:209) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:129) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConsumer.receive(ActiveMQJMSConsumer.java:66) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    ... 3 more
[ERROR] 2022-06-24 10:30:04.575 [GS-EventLoadMessageProcessorThread] load - AMQ219017: Consumer is closed
javax.jms.IllegalStateRuntimeException: AMQ219017: Consumer is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.JmsExceptionUtils.convertToRuntimeException(JmsExceptionUtils.java:59) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConsumer.receive(ActiveMQJMSConsumer.java:68) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at com.test.data.core.messaging.dataload.BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.processMessagesInBatch(BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.java:108) [test-core-base-data-loader-22.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.test.data.core.messaging.dataload.BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.run(BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.java:80) [test-core-base-data-loader-22.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: AMQ219017: Consumer is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.checkClosed(ClientConsumerImpl.java:951) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(ClientConsumerImpl.java:198) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(ClientConsumerImpl.java:382) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.getMessage(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:209) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:129) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConsumer.receive(ActiveMQJMSConsumer.java:66) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQObjectClosedException: AMQ219017: Consumer is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.checkClosed(ClientConsumerImpl.java:951) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(ClientConsumerImpl.java:198) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(ClientConsumerImpl.java:382) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.getMessage(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:209) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:129) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConsumer.receive(ActiveMQJMSConsumer.java:66) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    ... 3 more
Exception in thread "DataLoad-EventLoadMessageProcessorThread" Exception in thread "GS-EventLoadMessageProcessorThread" javax.jms.IllegalStateRuntimeException: AMQ219019: Session is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.JmsExceptionUtils.convertToRuntimeException(JmsExceptionUtils.java:59)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSContext.recover(ActiveMQJMSContext.java:364)
    at com.test.data.core.messaging.dataload.BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.processMessagesInBatch(BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.java:149)
    at com.test.data.core.messaging.dataload.BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.run(BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.java:80)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: AMQ219019: Session is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.checkClosed(ClientSessionImpl.java:2069)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.rollback(ClientSessionImpl.java:1007)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.rollback(ClientSessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession.recover(ActiveMQSession.java:341)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSContext.recover(ActiveMQJMSContext.java:362)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: ActiveMQObjectClosedException[errorType=OBJECT_CLOSED message=AMQ219019: Session is closed]
    ... 8 more
javax.jms.IllegalStateRuntimeException: AMQ219019: Session is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.JmsExceptionUtils.convertToRuntimeException(JmsExceptionUtils.java:59)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSContext.recover(ActiveMQJMSContext.java:364)
    at com.test.data.core.messaging.dataload.BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.processMessagesInBatch(BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.java:149)
    at com.test.data.core.messaging.dataload.BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.run(BaseDataLoaderEventLoadMessageProcessor.java:80)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: AMQ219019: Session is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.checkClosed(ClientSessionImpl.java:2069)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.rollback(ClientSessionImpl.java:1007)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.rollback(ClientSessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession.recover(ActiveMQSession.java:341)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSContext.recover(ActiveMQJMSContext.java:362)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: ActiveMQObjectClosedException[errorType=OBJECT_CLOSED message=AMQ219019: Session is closed]
    ... 8 more
```

Logs is start is called without calling stop

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:867) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createContext(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:306) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    ... 139 more
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:703) ~[artemis-core-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:865) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createContext(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:306) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    ... 139 more
```

EDIT 2: Now sometimes threads are going into BLOCKED state while stopping the server

```
Thread-6
Stack Trace is:
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.base@11.0.15/Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.base@11.0.15/Thread.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.sleep(java.base@11.0.15/TimeUnit.java:446)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.lock(FileLockNodeManager.java:442)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.writeFileLockStatus(FileLockNodeManager.java:329)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.setPaused(FileLockNodeManager.java:309)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.pauseLiveServer(FileLockNodeManager.java:269)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.close(LiveOnlyActivation.java:104)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.stop(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1393)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.stop(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1192)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.stop(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1176)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.stop(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:987)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.stop(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:981)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.EmbeddedActiveMQ.stop(EmbeddedActiveMQ.java:168)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say what exactly be happening without more details (e.g. logging from the broker), but in general behavior you're seeing is what I would expect. When the broker is unable to perform operations on the message store (e.g. file-system, database, etc.) this is considered a "critical" error and the broker will shut itself down. Once you restore connectivity you need to restart the broker, and there's no evidence that you're doing that.

You can register a callback with your embedded broker to be alerted when certain life-cycle events occur. Use `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl#registerActivateCallback` and pass it an `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActivateCallback` implementation. You could probably use this callback to restart the broker automatically in case of a failure of this kind.

Generally speaking I would recommend you use the file-based journal rather than JDBC as performance will be much better and it will be more robust.

Comment: Many thanks @Justin for quick reply. Yes, I was not restarting the broker earlier. After "stop and start" its working fine. 
However only starting the broker is not working as the broker is still in "Started" state. So I believe the handling/cleanup is not proper in this scenario and can be improved. Please correct me if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. I would need more details about what is happening on the broker when the DB connection fails to comment further.

Comment: I registered the ActivateCallback and can see that preDeActivate, deActivate, stop is called if DB is unreachable. Error log is

```

Comment: I have updated the question with the logs if DB connection fails and also in case server is started again without calling Stop. Works fine if Stop and then Start is called.

Comment: Sometimes threads are going into BLOCKED state while restarting the server. I have added the call stack in the Original question.
Can you please suggest what can be wrong here?

Comment: That thread isn't in the `BLOCKED` state. It's in the `TIMED_WAITING` state because it's trying to acquire a lock on the journal which apparently it's unable to do. By default the broker will wait _forever_ to acquire the lock. However, you can change this using `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration#setJournalLockAcquisitionTimeout` (measured in milliseconds).

Comment: Thanks Justin. I will try that. I have few doubts in respect to this:

1. Why the thread was unable to take the lock? What went wrong here?
2. If I set the `journalLockAcquisitionTimeout` say 60secs then What are the consequences if lock is not acquired within the 60 secs? Will the broker stop and subsequently start properly?

By the way I tried to set the `journal-lock-acquisition-timeout` in the broker.xml file but the value is not being set. I will try to set it i the Java code.

Comment: I have no idea why the lock can't be acquired. If the lock can't be acquired then a `ActiveMQLockAcquisitionTimeoutException` will be thrown which will trigger a `NodeManagerException` which will be logged and the shutdown process will continue on as normal. I'm not sure why setting `journal-lock-acquisition-timeout` in `broker.xml` isn't working.

Comment: For what it's worth, adding more and more questions to an existing question isn't really the way Stack Overflow works. Comments are for basic clarification. You should probably create one or more new questions for additional issues.